# Invoke a function in a fixed piece of code / expose an object from wrapper class

Tags: c#, oop, dictionary, delegates, wrapper

This might be a weird question.
I have a "piece of code" that I need to "wrap" some functions with.
To be more concise, I am building a wrapper class for a dictionary, and I have some "pre" and "post" action to do, all in a try-catch-finally block, where in the middle, I want to invoke a function.

What I am actually doing is exposing all the dictionary methods (to comply with the interface IDictionary), and I want/need to implement them all, and each one should be "inserted" inside my "piece of code". For example, this is my `ContainsKey(TKey key)`:

```
public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        bool IsLockTaken = false;

        try
        {
            // Acquire the lock:
            Monitor.TryEnter(SyncRoot, MonitorEnterTimeout, ref IsLockTaken);
            if (!IsLockTaken)
            {
                Log(@"Failed to Enter a monitor.");
                return false;
            }

            /* INVOKE HERE */
            return MyDict.ContainsKey(key); 
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Log(String.Format("Error: {0}", ex.ToString()));
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (IsLockTaken)
            {
                Monitor.Exit(SyncRoot);
            }
        } 
    }
```

So what I really need is for **every** function, to put the invocation in the "INVOKE HERE" part.
Is there a nice, correct way to do this, without code dups?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a function that itself takes a function and always does pre- and post processing like this:

```
public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
{
   bool result = false;
   WrapFunction(() => { result = MyDict.ContainsKey(key); });

   return result;
}

public void Clear()
{
   WrapFunction(() => MyDict.Clear());
}

private void WrapFunction(Action<T> action)
{
    bool IsLockTaken = false;

    try
    {
        // Acquire the lock:
        Monitor.TryEnter(SyncRoot, MonitorEnterTimeout, ref IsLockTaken);
        if (!IsLockTaken)
        {
            Log(@"Failed to Enter a monitor.");
            return;
        }

        action(); 
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Log(String.Format("Error: {0}", ex.ToString()));
        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (IsLockTaken)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(SyncRoot);
        }
    } 
}
```

You will have to check your error condition handling though. Obviously, with a generic `T`, returning `false` will not be enough. Maybe you need an additional parameter to return on error.

I have changed it so you can handle actions as well as functions.

Comment: Good solution, although you can't reuse it for void methods. Any idea how to reuse the code for voids?

Comment: @MotiAzu I added something to handle actions as well as functions.

Comment: Creative! You can even create a `WrapFunction` that accepts `Func<T>` with the same idea